# How to stop login from customerLogin observer

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, event-observer, login

I would like to deny login for a customer group. Following [an example](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.de/2011/12/create-magento-extension-that-will-only.html) I got a working observer but I am not able to stop the login process:

```
public function customerLogin($observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if ($customer->getData('group_id') == 4)
    {
         $session->setCustomer(Mage::getModel('customer/customer'))->setId(null);
         Mage::throwException(__('This account is not activated.'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, you just need to unset the details stored against the customer/session.

```
public function customerLogin($observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

    if ($customer->getData('group_id') == 4)
    {
        $session->setId(null)
           ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
           ->getCookie()->delete('customer');

        Mage::throwException(__('This account is not activated.'));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236912/magento-redirect-from-observer-that-always-works) and now this works, but [Luke's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7566/137) solution is better.

```
// redirect to new page
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('index'));
Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();

// Logout
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();

exit;
```

Note, that it stops working if you logout before redirecting or if you `throwException()`.